# Error - Method select(String) is not applicable for the arguments (RegularExpression)

Tags: java, regex

I am sending in a `datapool` value of variable `MCAS` District which has a regex value as (dotstar)000045(dotstar) 
But I am not able to use this regex `RDist` with `select`.

I get the following error message:

"The method select(String) in the type SelectGuiSubitemTestObject is not applicable for the arguments (RegularExpression)"

My code as below:

```
try
{
    SelectMCASDistrict(dpString("MCAS District"));
}
catch (ObjectNotFoundException e)
{
    logInfo("MCAS District Not found");
}

public static void SelectMCASDistrict(String Dist)
{
    GuiTestObject textObj = findTextObjectDist();
    if (textObj != null)
    {
        RegularExpression RDist = new RegularExpression (Dist, false);
        ((SelectGuiSubitemTestObject) textObj).select(RDist);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mainly passing a `RegularExpression` object to a method that is actually expecting a `String`.

If you believe it should receive a `RegularExpression` object, please make sure you are casting your `textObj` to the right `SelectGuiSubitemTestObject` class and not to one on a different version or `package`.

**Probably** what you are suppose to pass is a regular expression string and not this called RegularExpression object.

Meaning, that probably you want to do is pass `Dist` directly.

```
((SelectGuiSubitemTestObject) textObj).select(Dist);
```